MUI x-data-grid doesn't respect vertical cell alignment after update to 7.2.0
I've just updated my MUI app to the latest version of npm packages. This includes upgrading x-data-grid to from 5.17.9 to 7.2.0.
In my app I use a grid with some of the columns populated using renderCell property:
const cell = (props: GridRenderCellParams<any, string>): JSX.Element => (
  <Typography sx={isGood} key={props.value}>
    {props.value}
  </Typography>
);

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'text',
    headerName: 'TEXT',
    renderCell: cell,
    // ...
  },
];

It used to work nice, but after the update the cells lost their vertical alignment and now they stay at the top:

Before the cells used to be nicely centered both vertically and horiazontally:

Any idea what has changed and how I can restore the previous outlook?
Here's a short snippet that gives an idea of what does my code look like:

export const isGood = {
  color: 'green',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
};

const cell = (props: GridRenderCellParams<any, string>): JSX.Element => (
  <Typography sx={isGood} key={props.value}>
    {props.value}
  </Typography>
);

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'text',
    headerName: 'TEXT',
    align: 'center',
    headerAlign: 'center',
    width: 150,
    renderCell: cell,
    editable: false,
    flex: 1,
    disableColumnMenu: true,
    sortable: false,
  },
];

const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'T1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'T2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'T3',
  },
];

export default function RenderCellGrid() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        hideFooter
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        disableColumnSelector
        autoHeight
        columnHeaderHeight={40}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        rowHeight={85}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


After digging for a while, I found the reason in the migration guide:
https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-data-grid-v6/#css-classes-and-styling
It says:

The cell element isn't display: flex by default. You can add display: 'flex' on the column definition to restore the behavior.

I set the 'flex' on my column and that restored the previous outlook automatically.

Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. You can validate your answer!

replace your cell with
const cell = (props: GridRenderCellParams<any, string>): JSX.Element => (
    <Box sx={{height:85,display:"flex", flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>
        <Typography sx={isGood} key={props.value}>
            {props.value}
        </Typography>
    </Box>
);


An easy fix can be adding component={"span"}, this removes the extra margin/padding.
<Typography component={"span"} sx={isGood} key={props.value}>
    {props.value}
 </Typography>

